# Getting initial values of non-primitive types from another Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, react.js

I have a file where I keep some initial values for some form fields base on field type. Some of them are primitive values, like `'' or 0 or false` but some of them are non-primitive reference values, like `[] or {}`. For example:

**INITIAL_VALUES.js**

```
const INITIAL_VALUES= {
  SINGLE_CHOICE: '',
  MULTIPLE_CHOICE: [],
  OBJECT: {},
  BOOLEAN: false,
  NUMBER: 0,
  STRING: ''
};

export default INITIAL_VALUES;
```

The fact is that I have to **be careful when using non-primitive initial values, because since they come as reference,** I might change them, and get them a second time with some residual value, instead of being empty.

I've tought about some options to deal with this:

---

**OPTION #1**

Make the `INITIAL_VALUES.js` export a function that returns the new values object and call that function inside my component.

Example:

**getInitialValues.js**

```
function getInitialValues() {
  return({
    SINGLE_CHOICE: '',
    MULTIPLE_CHOICE: [],
    OBJECT: {},
    // and so on...
  });
}

export default getInitialValues;
```

**SomeComponent.js**

```
import getInitialValues from './getInitialValues'

function SomeComponent() {
  const INITIAL_VALUES = getInitialValues();
}
```

---

**OPTION #2**

Keep the initial values as an object and everytime I use them, I need to check if it's a non-primitive and create a new one (instead of using the same reference from `INITIAL_VALUES`).

Example:

**SomeComponent.js**

```
myVariable = INITIAL_VALUES[fieldType];

if (Array.isArray(myVariable)) {
  myVariable = [...myVariable];                   // CREATE A NEW ARRAY
}
else if (typeof(myVariable)  === 'object') {
  myVariable = {...myVariable};                   // CREATE A NEW OBJECT
}
```

---

**OPTION #3**

Use only non-primitive values. And set `null` instead of empty arrays `[]` and empty objects `{}`.

Example:

**INITIAL_VALUES.js**

```
const INITIAL_VALUES= {
  SINGLE_CHOICE: '',
  MULTIPLE_CHOICE: null,
  OBJECT: null,
  BOOLEAN: false,
  NUMBER: 0,
  STRING: ''
};
```

But doing so, whenever I try to populate those fields, I'll need to check if the object/array exists, and create it if it doesn't.

Example

**SomeComponent.js**

```
function pushValueToArrayField(newValue) {
  setState((prevState) => {
    const aux = {...prevState};
    if (aux.someArrayField === null) {
      aux.someArrayField = [];
    }
    aux.someArrayField.push(newValue);
    return aux;
  });
}
```

What is my best option here?

Comment: "I have a file" How big? What does your current code look like, exactly? On Code Review, we don't deal well with hypotheticals. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic] and consider what you really want to ask here.

Comment: The `INITIAL_VALUES.js` file is my exact file. And the options are the consequences that I'll have to embrace whatever road I take.

Comment: Why don't you have the default for your textarea component in your textarea-component.js, for your multiple choice component in multiple-choice-component.js, etc?

Comment: @Mohrn because then my initial values would be hard coded across multiple files. And I might want to change them at some point.

Comment: I've ended up choosing OPTION #1 and it's working alright so far!

Comment: Cant you just freeze it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Comment: @konijn no.. I really need a new instance everytime because I'll modify it.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I've ended up doing:

**INITIAL_VALUES.js**

```
function GET_FEATURE_TYPES_INITIAL_VALUES() {
  const FEATURE_TYPE_INITIAL_VALUES = {
    SINGLE_CHOICE: '',
    MULTIPLE_CHOICE: [],
    BOOLEAN: false,
    NUMBER: 0,
    STRING: ''
  };
  return FEATURE_TYPE_INITIAL_VALUES;
}

function GET_FILTER_TYPES_INITIAL_VALUES() {
  const FILTER_TYPE_INITIAL_VALUES = {
    NUMBER_RANGE_ALLOW_MULTIPLE: [],
    NUMBER_ACUM_RANGE_ALLOW_SINGLE: [],
    SINGLE_CHOICE_ALLOW_SINGLE: [],
    SINGLE_CHOICE_ALLOW_MULTIPLE: [],
    MULTIPLE_CHOICE_ALLOW_MULTIPLE: [],
    BOOLEAN_ALLOW_MULTIPLE: [],
    STRING_ALLOW_MULTIPLE: []
  };
  return FILTER_TYPE_INITIAL_VALUES;
}

function GET_FIELD_TYPES_INITIAL_VALUES() {
  const FIELD_TYPE_INITIAL_VALUES = {
    STRING_FIELD: '',
    BOOLEAN_FIELD: '',
    NUMBER_FIELD: 0,
    ARRAY_STRINGS_FIELD: [],
    ARRAY_OBJECTS_FIELD: [],
    OBJECT_FIELD: {}
  };
  return FIELD_TYPE_INITIAL_VALUES;
}

export {
  GET_FEATURE_TYPES_INITIAL_VALUES,
  GET_FILTER_TYPES_INITIAL_VALUES,
  GET_FIELD_TYPES_INITIAL_VALUES
};
```

**SomeComponent.js**

```
import { GET_FEATURE_TYPES_INITIAL_VALUES } from '@constants/INITIAL_VALUES';

function SomeComponent() {
  const FEATURE_TYPES_INITIAL_VALUES = GET_FEATURE_TYPES_INITIAL_VALUES();

  // FRESH NEW INITIAL_VALUES AVAILABLE ON EVERY RENDER
}
```

Comment: This neither follows best practices for React (defaultProps) nor for Javascript (camel case).